# Difference between scipy.optimize.fmin_powell() and scipy.optimize.minimize(..., method='Powell')

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy

What is the difference between [scipy.optimize.fmin_powell()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin_powell.html) and [scipy.optimize.minimize()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html#r162) with the method specified as 'Powell'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only difference between the two is the interface. Under the hood they are doing the exact same computations.

The `minimize()` function is a more recently-added wrapper (available since scipy version 0.14) that provides a more convenient uniform interface for the various solvers available in `scipy.optimize`. `minimize(method='powell')` and `fmin_powell()` both internally call the same `_minimize_powell()` private function that does the bulk of the work.